# Ajax is not getting the json response from server

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jersey-2.0

I am new to jquery/Ajax .
My Server code return the json data
But it did not received in  jquery/ajax .
for which i have tried 
this is my ajax request code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/eduvib/webapi/question/getPaper', 
        dataType:'json',
        data: {"subject":subject,"cls":classes,"diff":dificultylevel,"marks":marks},
        success:function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));

        },
        error:function() {
             alert("request failed");
        }                 
    });
```

And this is my server Side Code Which also return the response

```
@POST
@Path("/getPaper")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public List<Question> getPaper(@FormParam("subject") String subject, @FormParam("cls") String cls,
        @FormParam("diff") int diff, @FormParam("marks") int marks) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Question> mylist = new ArrayList<Question>();
     mylist = getQuestionList.getData(subject, cls, diff, marks);
     System.out.println(mylist);
     return mylist;

}
```

And this is the Logs at server side which prints the response after hitting the ajax request

```
   [Question [questionid=questionid, questiontext=kk, topicname=k,...... complete list
```

But in Ajax request its not getting

Comment: you have mentioned `dataType:'json',` so you should send response in JSON from server side

Comment: @PankajMakwana I am sending response from server in json. as You can see in my Server code

Comment: this is not valid json what you are returning, look into how to convert it to legit json

Comment: @N.Ivanov there is no issue with server side i think . because It is working  fine in Postman

Comment: ok then what do you get back as a response in your browser? do you get anything in the console? if not what is the response from dev tools?

Comment: In Postman is working fine . and being a Post Request with data  i could check it only Postman not in browser

Comment: try alert(response) in js. stringify is to convert object to JSON. From json is JSON.parse